# What are some games of chance that existed before 1500?

Tags: society, magic, medieval

I am writing a scene where someone wins a dragon egg in a game of chance. Then I realized, what game of chance? The game must have existed before 1500. Please provide a basic overview of the rules. If it is not a real game, but a made up concept for a game of chance (which I would love also), please explain the basic rules also. If it is to much to ask (I really don’t want this question closed) what country invented the game (just out of curiosity.)

-the game must have been invented before 1600, unless it is a made up game.

-the game must be a game of chance. (Although it could be unfair in some way.)

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm Hagrid, anyone?

Comment: What? Do you not understand the question?

Comment: It's not really a world building question, but a story point.

Comment: Games are interesting fodder for the worldbuilder.  I'd strongly suggest you edit this question to provide the fictional worldbuilding context this forum requires.  Since almost every real world game of chance currently played descends in some way or other from very much older games of chance, it might help if you were to specify what kinds of cultural millieu you're dealing with, what kinds of people are playing, what technologies (or thaumologies) exist, and the like.

Comment: @elemtilas I didn’t because it doesn’t matter. You closed it didn’t you? I just wanted to know some of the games of chance played before 1500. It doesn’t matter who’s playing it. It doesn’t matter where it comes from. Open the question back up please.

Comment: Already the Roman soldiers played "dicing". They threw two six-sided dices, and the greater sum of the dices decided, who wins. (As I can remember, having the same number on both dices were stronger.)

Comment: If it doesn't matter, why are you wasting our time with your nonsense? Did I close it --- did you bother looking at the list of members who voted to close, or are you just drawing an assumption out of thin air? Problem: we're not here to entertain you or provide a google lookup service for your idle curiosity. You've been here long enough to know better. Go review the [tour] and the [help] and [learn what this forum is about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about); and after you edit your question accordingly, we'll consider reopening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AlexP beat me to it in comments again, but I am used to that.  It actually is kind of reassuring now.

So what old game to play with dice?  How about [backgammon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon)?

[image: backgammon medieval london]

https://medievallondon.ace.fordham.edu/exhibits/show/medieval-london-objects/gamepiece

> Backgammon dates back to about 5,000 years, and is said to have
> originated from somewhere in the Middle East or Asia, specifically
> from Iraq. The game was likely to have come to England during the
> eleventh century and gained popularity among the wealthy and the
> clergy. Backgammon requires a person to role the dice and move the
> game pieces accordingly until one person removes all of their pieces
> from the board and wins.

Comment: Backgammon is not really a game of chance. In backgammon, chance has a significant influence in an individual game (or "line"), skill becomes dominant in a match. (And it has been *legally* declared a game of skill, at least in the USA.)

Comment: @AlexP - agreed; dice is a purer game of chance.  But winning a dragons egg in a backgammon match has a fine medieval feel to it.

Comment: Yes it does! Upvoted.

Comment: It doesn’t actually matter that much if it is not a game of chance. Any games are fine.

Comment: I agree. Definitely a nice medieval feel.